# how do you print ggplot output inside a for loop in sweave

Tags: r, latex, sweave

prod_data is a data frame that has cpu usage data. I need to go though each application in applciation vectore and print out chart for all graphs. Looks like, when I do print(p), it is not printing. Can anybody tell me what I am missing here. I need to print insinde the for loop to print all of the applications cpu one at a time.

```
<<results=tex, meval=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
    application<-c("Web","Farm")

    for (product in application){ 
      cat(paste("\\section{",product,"}", sep=""))
      p<-ggplot(subset(prod_data, App %in% product),aes(Date, Cpubusy, group=Hostname, fill=Hostname))+geom_area()+
      facet_wrap(~Hostname)+theme_bw()+
      ggtitle(paste(product, " %CPU Usage"))+ theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="blue", fill="#b2d8ff"),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))+scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdYlGn")
      print(p)


      }
    @
```

Comment: When you say "print", do you mean you want to save the resulting visual plot in `p` to a file?

Comment: @David, I want to show the ggplot output in pdf file. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: My initial answer suggested using [ggsave](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggsave.html). However, the issue is clarified as wanting to have the plot shown within sweave, not saved outside of the document itself.

Comment: @David, I need to implement it in a way that bunch of charts need to show up in one pdf file via sweave.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not familiar with sweave. Check out [this Git gist](https://gist.github.com/chlalanne/882297) and see if it helps.